# classification in R

Tags: r, classification

I am trying to do naive bayes classification in R. I have seen this example in following link.

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Mining_Algorithms_In_R/Classification/Na%C3%AFve_Bayes

Only 2 lines are there. First classify and then predict.

```
> classifier<-naiveBayes(iris[,1:4], iris[,5]) 
> table(predict(classifier, iris[,-5]), iris[,5])
```

This same code on "iris dataset" working fine. But when i applied the same on my dataset, I am getting some errors.

My dataset contains 4 attributes and 4th attribute the class attribute.

```
> str(data1)
'data.frame':   1370 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ TenScore     : num  85 84.2 67.2 91.5 79.3 ...
 $ TwelthScore  : num  69 87.9 67.5 82.7 72.4 ...
 $ GDegreeScore : num  63.3 70.7 61.3 78.2 62.1 ...
 $ Got_Admission: chr  "No" "No" "No" "No" ...
```

So, I tried this.

```
> classifier<-naiveBayes(data1[,1:3], data1[,4]) 
> table(predict(classifier, data1[,-4]), data1[,4])
Error in table(predict(classifier, data1[, -4]), data1[, 4]) : 
  all arguments must have the same length
```

I am getting above error when I am executing the command. When I just use predict, its giving me following output.

```
> predict(classifier, data1[,-4])
factor(0)
Levels:

str(data1) 'data.frame': 1370 obs. of 4 variables: 
$ TenScore : num 85 84.2 67.2 91.5 79.3 ... 
$ TwelthScore : num 69 87.9 67.5 82.7 72.4 ... 
$ GDegreeScore : num 63.3 70.7 61.3 78.2 62.1 ... 
$ Got_Admission: chr "No" "No" "No" "No" ...
```

Please explain me whats the errors about and how to solve?

Comment: You need to post at the very least str(data1).

Comment: > str(data1)
'data.frame': 1370 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ TenScore     : num  85 84.2 67.2 91.5 79.3 ...
 $ TwelthScore  : num  69 87.9 67.5 82.7 72.4 ...
 $ GDegreeScore : num  63.3 70.7 61.3 78.2 62.1 ...
 $ Got_Admission: chr  "No" "No" "No" "No" ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can produce the same error by changing the 5th column of iris to character:

```
> iris[ , 5] <- as.character(iris[ , 5] )
> classifier<-naiveBayes(iris[,1:4], iris[,5]) 
>  table(predict(classifier, iris[,-5]), iris[,5])
Error in table(predict(classifier, iris[, -5]), iris[, 5]) : 
  all arguments must have the same length
#  The fix -------->
 iris[ , 5] <- factor(as.character(iris[ , 5] ))
 classifier<-naiveBayes(iris[,1:4], iris[,5]) 
 table(predict(classifier, iris[,-5]), iris[,5])
#  ---- output--------            
             setosa versicolor virginica
  setosa         50          0         0
  versicolor      0         47         3
  virginica       0          3        47
```

So you should probably do this:

```
  data1$ Got_Admission <- factor(data1$ Got_Admission)
```

If your 'Got_Admission' column is not in good order you will get confusing results (the GIGO effect). You should first look at the contents with:

```
table(data1$ Got_Admission)
```

Comment: I am getting following result
`
            No  Yes
      No  1320   50
      Yes    0    0`

Can you please explain what it meant?

Comment: The table not coming properly. Result contains 3 rows in table. first: *, No, Yes  second:No, 1320, 50 and third: yes, 0, 0

Comment: I have same problem. I have converted response values to factor value yet i am continue to get same error "all arguments must have the same length"

Comment: Well,  with the `iris` data set, I do not get any error using the code (and the recommended correction)  in my four-year-old answer.